# Show that $2\pi i f(z) = \int_C \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z} \, d\zeta - \int_C \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta -\frac{1}{\bar z}} \, d\zeta$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $f$ be differentiable inside and on the unit circle, centered at the origin, traversed anticlockwise. Show that for $0<|z|<1$ $$2\pi i f(z) = \int_C \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z} \, d\zeta - \int_C \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta -\frac{1}{\bar z}} \, d\zeta$$

I know that the first of the two integrals equals the LHS by Cauchy's integral formula, and so the second must be zero. I know that Cauchy's theorem says that if the second function is holomorphic on some simply connected region containing $C$ then the integral is $0$. I think this means I need to show that $|1/\bar z|\geq1$. How do I do this?

Comment: What is the relation between $\lvert w\rvert$ and $\lvert 1/w\rvert$?

Comment: Since $0 < \vert z \vert < 1$,
$$\vert 1/\bar{z} \vert = 1/\vert z \vert > 1.$$

Comment: @EthanAlwaise Oh I see, I wasn't spotting that $|z|=|\bar z|$. Thank you.